# LINQ : Checking against each other item in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have class like below

```
public class Item
{   
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public long GroupingId {get;set;}
    public long Weight {get;set;}
    public long Tolerance {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have list of `Items` with different grouping id. Lets say

```
List<Item> items  = GetItems();
```

Now I need to group based groupings id, and make check for each item in that group against each other. How would I do that in **LINQ** efficiently. Any help much appreciated.

```
IDictionary<long, long[]> matches = new Dictionary<long, long[]>();

foreach(groupedItems in items.GroupBy(p=>p.GroupingId))
{    
  foreach(item in groupItems)
  {
    // Check item with other items in group items 
    // and if condition is correct take those 2 items.
    // lets say the condition is 
    // (item.Weighting - other.Weighting) > item.Tolerance
    // duplicates could be removed 
    // lets condition for 1,2 is done means no need to do 2 against 1

    var currentItem = item;    
    var matchedOnes = 
         groupItems.Where(p => (Math.Abs(p.Weighting - currentItem.Weighting) > currentItem .Tolerance) && p.Id != currentItem.Id)
                   .ToList();

    if (!matchedOnes.Any())
        continue;

    matches.Add(currentItem.Id, matchedOnes .Select(p=>p.Id).ToArray());
  }
}
```

I did like above, but its giving duplicates(1,2 and 2,1 are duplicates).. How would I remove the duplicate checks

Comment: What exactly checks do you want to do? It seems that you want to throw all items with difference more than tolerance, but in this case you should compare value with average value, but you compare with other values in group. In this case, if you have any pair of items with difference more than tolerance you will throw away whole group.

Comment: I need to check the difference in weighting of two items in the group with greater than the item 1 tolerance.

Math.Abs(item1.weighting-item2.weighting) > item1.Tolerance

Comment: first make distinct list of GroupingId 
Like List<long> lst = items.Select(h => h.GroupingId).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Please, define answer field.

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi I have updated it. There is no field called answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simple change, try exchanging `p.Id != answer.Id` for `p.Id > answer.Id` in your `groupItems.Where(...)` line.

Comment: Excellent, if answer means what you think and belongs to groupItems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
        var items = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
        {
            new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(2, 2)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(2, 2)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(3, 2)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(3, 3)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(4, 4)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(4, 3)
            , new Tuple<int, int>(4, 4)
        }.Select(kp => new { id = kp.Item1, data = kp.Item2 });

        var res = (
            from i1 in items
            from i2 in items
            where i1.id < i2.id
                /* Custom Filter goes there */
                && i1.data == i2.data
            select new { i1 = i1, i2 = i2 }
        );
```

Comment: Check out `Tuple.Create` which can save you a couple of characters since you need not specify the generic types:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, items.Count()).SelectMany(index => 
  items.Skip(index + 1).Select(right => new { left = items.elementAt(index), right }));

var matches = pairs.Where(item => 
               (item.left.Weight - item.right.Weight) > item.left.Tolerance);
```

The first part creates all the pairs that have to be compared like (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3) for a collection of 3 items.
The second part selects the pairs that match your condition.

I've also removed the grouping code which you already figured out (items = groupItems).

Comment: Is it me, or is this a scenario where LINQ causes completely unreadable code?